# replacing element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `<form>`s on my page that I want to replace with `<button>`s. The thing that is causing me difficulty is that I want to use the value of the `<form>`'s submit input as the html for the button.

```
<form action="/postcomment/" method="post">
<inputs>
.
. 
.
<input type="submit" value="Reply">
</form>
```

Becomes

```
<button class="postcomment">Reply</button>
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around the chaining here. I need to grab the data  values (e.g. "Reply") and then insert them into the button elements in one jQuery operation (or else manage the ordering with something like `.index()`) and I haven't figure out how to do that yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just edit the html?

Comment: Could you explain more generally what you are trying to accomplish? The way you are going about this seems to be very convoluted and out of the ordinary.

Comment: The form sends the user to a page with a new comment box if javascript is not available. If javascript is available this button replaces the form and, when the button is clicked, a javascript function will insert the comment box. Is this ridiculous? I'm teaching myself, so it very well could be.

Comment: @Hank It would be best to put a `.submit()` event handler on the form, and cancel the default event (`preventDefault()`). This way, without JS, the form will be posted, but if there is JS, the submit will be cancelled and you can do your magic.

Comment: @baz Thanks! I think that is the solution to the underlying problem. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mch86/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').each(function(){
        button = $('<button>' + $('input[type="submit"]', this).val() + '</button>').addClass($(this).attr('action').replace(/\//g, ''));
        $(this).replaceWith(button);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<button>').text(this.value).addClass('postcomment');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ung47/)

This will replace all of your submit buttons (`<input type="submit">`) with a `<button>`, keeping the text on the button.

[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) allows you to use a function as its parameter, which has a reference to the individual submits themselves (`this`).

Comment: +1 huh, i've used jQuery for years and never noticed `replaceWith`. Learn something new every day...

Comment: That only replaces the submit button -- he said he wants to replace the entire form.

Comment: I understood that OP wants to replace the whole form, not just the input.

Comment: @mblase75 Replacing the whole form with a button would not make sense at all. So I guessed this is what he wants. Waiting for the OP's clarification.

Comment: @mblase75 If you know the reason, most of the time you can offer a better solution. And if he really wants to replace the whole form, he can do so using my method anyways (with a few small changes).

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you have multiple forms:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        var str = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').val();
        $(this).replaceWith($('<button/>').addClass("postcomment").text(str));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var label = $('form input:submit').val();
var action = $('form').attr('action').replace(/\//g, '');

var button = $('<button />', { class: action});
button.html(label);
$('form').replaceWith(button)
```

;

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/be3af/1/